# How to get rid of the Error Message for calling a text file in SageMath

Tags: matrix, input, output, sage, determinants

I want to input a matrix from a text file and run it in SageMath.
The name of the file is Matrix.It is located in the D-drive and it contains a square matrix of order 4.

I changed the the name of the file from Matrix.txt to Matrix.sage.
I then wrote

```
load('Matrix.sage');
```

But I got an error message which read

> Traceback (click to the left of this block for traceback)
>   ...
>   IOError: did not find file 'Matrix.sage' to load or attach

Is it possible for Sage-Math to take input a matrix which is stored in a Text File?

I want to input the matrix from the text file and find its determinant in SageMath.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely load other files, but you have to load them with correct syntax.    If you have a `.sage` file it must be composed of Sage commands, and that (or a Python file) is the only such file that can be loaded in this way.

The easiest thing for you to do is, if you have the matrix already, just make it a Sage command and have the file be that.  E.g. if your file is

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
0 0 0 0 
3 3 3 3
```

you could do some very basic text processing to change it into

```
M = matrix(4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

or

```
L = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [0,0,0,0], [3,3,3,3] ]
M = matrix(L)
```

You may find [this answer](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/34915/load-contents-of-a-txt-file-into-a-sage-worksheet/?answer=34976) or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2135857/24113)helpful as well in terms of actual reading text files into Sage (same as for Python, really).